# nginx setup a reverse proxy for a subdirectory and the page is blank

Tags: nginx, server

I am trying to setup a sub directory/route like example.com/nodeapp

and I have a react + express application (nodeapp) which runs on port 5000, I already setup a reverse proxy so visitor browses the example.com/nodeapp would be the react + express app (nodeapp).

However, I am having a issue that browsing the example.com/nodeapp, the page is blank.

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

```
    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
    }

    location ^~ /nodeapp/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass    http://localhost:5000/;
    }
```

As you can see I also have a reverse proxy port 3000 for default (/) page, if I run the nodeapp on port 3000, and go to example.com ; the app works; it shows.

Moreover, I have a express app (express code only); it would display "hello world" on the page; If I run it on port 5000, and go to example.com/nodeapp it does work; it shows "hello world"

So I am assuming setting up the reverse proxy for sub directory/route for react + express application is not working???

Anyone have any solutions to for the nginx code so browsing the example.com/nodeapp would show the nodeapp?

In addition, I am receiving following errors
[image]